# print an image at the end of last page css

Tags: html, css

I have a html file and i need to print an image at the `end of last page`. I have tried the below css but not working

```
<div>test content</div>
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
<div>atestecontent</div>
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px;"><img src="android.png" width="63" height="91" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You only want to print the image? Nothing else?

Comment: I want to print all the contents in the html file along with the image at the end of last page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a print style sheet to your document. Then you just need to reset that position absolute to display:block; Remember to add the class to the div with absolute too.

```
<style media="print">
.remove-abs {
    position:static;
}

.page-break {
    page-break-before:always; 
}
</style>

<div>test content</div>
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
<div>atestecontent</div>
<div class="remove-abs page-break" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px;"><img src="android.png" width="63" height="91" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your code. But it prints at the end of the first page not at the end of last page.

Comment: Updated above, hopefully that works for you. Without seeing the content or the page, its very hard to help. If this doesn't work I recommend setting up a jsfiddle so we can help easier.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have tried your code. Now it get printed at the end of content not at the end of the page that is bottom of the last page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43256/discussion-between-lifeline-and-michael-tempest)